Python: IpyWidgets.Button() on_click not working
I have a simple function that takes input from a text drop down and generates random figures based on the input in the text box. issue is, i cannot get this to work with a button.on_click event. it simply does not work- I have tried so many different examples, but cannot get this to work. any ideas?
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as ipw
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

style = {'description_width': '100px'}  
layout = ipw.Layout(width='500px') 

index_dropdown = ipw.widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="Enter Figure Here:",
        style=style,
        layout=layout, 
        continuous_update=True,
    )
butt = ipw.widgets.Button(description='Get DF', disabled=False)
output = ipw.widgets.Output()  

def data_handling(tick)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(tick, 1), columns=list('A'))
    return df 


def pr_click(c):
    with output:
        clear_output(True)
        tick = index_dropdown.value 
        f_x = data_handling(tick)
        return f_x 

r = butt.on_click(lambda b: pr_click)

display(index_dropdown,butt, f_x)```

